# Why are my table rows appearing next to each other instead of on top?

Tags: html, css, html-table

So i have the below table, and i cant figure out why the first two table rows in the first table are appearing as if they were in the same row. Cant find a reason anywhere. I want them to appear as they you would expect, on top of one another in a column. Am i missing something here? https://jsfiddle.net/b4j2e1vq/

````
<html>
<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <script src="./jScript.js" async></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styleSheet.css">
            <h1> Energy saving calculator</h1>
        </header>
        <body>
                     

            <section class="savingCalc" id="paperTowelCalc" >
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3">Total Paper Towel Cost per annum</td>
                            <td rowspan="3"><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="papTowelCost" value="0"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3">Energy cost saving per annum by switching</td>
                            <td rowspan="3"><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="costSaveSwitch" value="0"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="handDryPDayInp">Number of hand dries/day*</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="handDryPDayInp" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="daysOpenInp">Days per annum washroom is open</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="daysOpenInp" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="costPerTowel">Cost per towel</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="costPerTowel" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="dispenserReplaceNum">Number of dispensers to be replaced </label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="dispenserReplaceNum" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
            </section>

           
        </body>




    </div>
</div>

</html>```
````

Comment: It is because of the `rowspan` given to the `td`. If you remove them, you will be able to see the expected results

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the rowspan though, is there no way to include both the rowspan and have them appear on top?

Comment: Could you describe why you need the rowspans? What do you expect that table to look like?

Comment: Trying to match what has been requested by somebody. I want the rows to be 3 times the height as default i guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want those `rowspan`, what you can do to get around is - You can add two empty rows between two `tr`

```
<section class="savingCalc" id="paperTowelCalc">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Total Paper Towel Cost per annum</td>
        <td rowspan="3"><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="papTowelCost" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Energy cost saving per annum by switching</td>
        <td rowspan="3"><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="costSaveSwitch" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

The issue here is that you are using `rowspan=3`, but there are just 2 rows there. The columns of the first row will try to take up the first two two columns for the next 3 rows. So as there will be no space left for the second row elements, this unexpected behaviour is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer here is to remove rowspan. Just mentioning for anyone who might face the same problem.

Since you need the rowspan though as you mentioned in the comments above, one possible solution is to add class names on your rows. Not very efficient but does the work:

```css
.row {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <script src="./jScript.js" async></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styleSheet.css">
        <h1> Energy saving calculator</h1>
      </header>

      <body>


        <section class="savingCalc" id="paperTowelCalc">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="row">
                <td rowspan="3">Total Paper Towel Cost per annum</td>
                <td rowspan="3"><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="papTowelCost" value="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="row">
                <td rowspan="3">Energy cost saving per annum by switching</td>
                <td rowspan="3"><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="costSaveSwitch" value="0"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>


          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td><label for="handDryPDayInp">Number of hand dries/day*</label></td>
              <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="handDryPDayInp" value="0"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="daysOpenInp">Days per annum washroom is open</label></td>
              <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="daysOpenInp" value="0"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="costPerTowel">Cost per towel</label></td>
              <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="costPerTowel" value="0"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="dispenserReplaceNum">Number of dispensers to be replaced </label></td>
              <td><input type="number" class="handDryerModelInput" id="dispenserReplaceNum" value="0"></td>
            </tr>


          </table>
        </section>


      </body>




    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. The codesnippet still shows the rows in question as the same height as all the other rows in the table, I need them to be 3 times the height as the default rows in the table if possible. Is this doable with rowspan?